# Can i move samba from device to another?

Tags: linux, samba, offline-files, oracle-linux, move

I downloaded the samba on my operating system (Oracle Linux 8), I want to copy it to another device that have the same operating system but without internet connection. Can I do that? if i can how to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @user1499239 You should contact here: https://www.samba.org/samba/archives.html